# VScode Python unresolved import using a module from the current folder

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

I'm running vscode from some `project/` folder and getting an "unresolved import" error in some `project/impl/` folder. In the `impl/` folder I have 2 Python files:

```py
# lib.py
class A():
    pass
```

```py
# run.py
from lib import A # vscode error here - unresolved import
...
```

When running `run.py` the Python interpreter finds the `lib` just fine but vscode shows an "unresolved import" error ([screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MZHEc.jpg)).

If I change the import line to `from .lib import implementation` (note the dot), I get the opposite behaviour where vscode resolves the import fine but the Python interpreter fails.

How should I import the lib or otherwise configure vscode to resolve imports from a local folder? (obviously I don't want to add the exact path of the local folder to the vscode config file since I would have to do so for every subfolder in the project)

Comment: Is the parent file of “lib.py” file and "run.py" file both "impl" folder? After I run it according to the information currently provided, it can be imported and used, so could you provide us with a complete file directory structure?

Comment: To reproduce - run vscode from some folder, create a subfolder and create the two files within the subfolder. I added a [screenshot](https://imgur.com/a/E3ZqNJc).

Comment: Once you have a project with subdirectories, it's better to create a (local) python package.

Comment: @Wups can you please explain further?

Answer (score 7):

When I used the python extension version 2018.12.1 in my computer, I got the same issue as you described.

Since this function is provided by the language service, and the python language service is provided by the python extension, it is recommended that you could try to use the latest version of the python extension(2020.8.106424).

In addition, you could use the extension "[Pylance](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-python.vscode-pylance)", which also provides excellent language services for python.

The project I created on my computer:

[image]

My environment:

VSCode Version: 1.48.2 (user setup)

OS: Windows_NT x64 10.0.18362

Python extension: 2020.8.106424

languageServer in `settings.json`:

```
 "python.languageServer": "Pylance",
```

Update1:

When the language service I use is "`Jedi`", the code also does not have this warning:

> `"python.languageServer": "Jedi",`

Update2:

Since this warning does not affect the execution result of the code, we could also turn off this kind of warning in the settings (`settings.json`):

```
"python.analysis.disabled": [
      "unresolved-import"
  ]
```

In this way, we can use `"python.languageServer": "Microsoft",`

Comment: I am running the latest version of the Python extension and the problem persists. The Pylance extension indeed solves this issue although I need to test what other changes it brings when installing it.

Comment: @gilad I updated my answer, and you could try to refer to it. In addition, "Pylance" is an extension developed by Microsoft that can work with python extensions and provide high-performance language support. You can refer to it: [Pylance](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-python.vscode-pylance)

Comment: Jedi seems to resolve the import correctly but whenever I change to jedi, vscode tries to revert back to the Microsoft language server. I wish I could configure the Microsoft language server to resolve these imports as well.

Comment: @gilad According to your description I added "Update2" in my answer, and you could refer to it.

Comment: Thank you, but the problem is not the underline warning. When the language server fails to resolve the import, it also skips the relevant lines during debugging and will also refuse to "go to definition - F12" on functions and classes defined in the imported file.

Comment: @gilad It is recommended that you use the "Pylance" language service, I can successfully use the "Go to definition" function when using it. And currently Microsoft’s development of language services has been transferred to "Pylance", Pylance will eventually replace Microsoft Language server. Please let us know if you encounter any issues while using it.

Answer (score 1):

You can add the folder to path of module searching for python using sys module.

```
import sys
sys.path.insert(1, "./impl/")

from lib import A
```

Note, the vs code can still underline the import line, but, it will work just fine when you run the program. Give it a try!

You can add more paths like this -

```
sys.path.insert(n, <path to folder>)
```

Keep care to use a new natural number in place of n for every new path.

Comment: The vscode underline is really my problem (this also has implications in debugging and navigating). The code runs fine otherwise.